# Android webview load more than one java script function in loadUrl method

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I use `loadUrl` function to call a JavaScript function inside my webview:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){var txt = window.getSelection();window.name= txt;window.cpjs.sendToAndroid(window.name);window.cpjs.sendTest(5);})()");
```

but how can I call more than one JavaScript function inside `loadUrl`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in a similar way to which you have above but define the functions in an anonymous parent function, then self-execute:

```
javascript:(function(){
    function firstFunction(){
        alert('First function called');
    }
    function secondFunction(){
       alert('Second function called');
    }

    firstFunction();
    secondFunction();
})()
```